# angular access a compoent in nested levels

Tags: angular

I got a parent component. Which might have many components with in it. And those all components might have a special component which i am interested in.

```
ParentComponent
     SubComponent1
           MySpecialComponent
      SubComponent2
           MySpecialCompoent
      SubComponent3
           SubSubComponent31
                MySpecialCompnoent
```

I am looking for ways to get instance of MySpecialCompnoent  from ParentComponent. Will @viewChildren works? MySpecialCompnoent  is never included directly in the parentcompoent.It might be below many levels.
I tried to access using @viewchildren ;but i get an empty array rather

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a service to relay messages between components that are not directly related - at this stage anyway, maybe if/when you're more fluent with Angular basics, look into state management with things like NgRX.

There's many ways to do this, but one might be:

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CommsService {
    somethingHappens:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

**component1.ts**

```
constructor(private comms: CommsService) {}
doSomething() {
    this.comms.somethingHappens.emit({
       oops: 'I accidentally a whole bottle'
    });
}
```

**component2.ts**

```
constructor(private comms: CommsService) {}
private subs:Subscription[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.subs = [
        this.comms.somethingHappens.subscribe(whatHappens => {
            this.doSomethingWithTheInfo(whatHappens);
            console.log(whatHappens.oops); // I accidentally a whole bottle
        });
    ];
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // No memory leaks, please
    this.subs.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
}
```